# Clear game board in tic-tac-toe to restart game only using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is my code but I don't quite get it on how to delete/clear the mark in markboard function in previous game to pave way for the new game. Below is my code. I think in markBoard(position, mark).clear(mark), there's some error to it but I don't know how to correct.

```
while(winnerIdentified){

let yesNo = prompt(`Play another game?(y/n)`);
console.log(`${yesNo}`);

if (restartGame(yesNo) == true){
    markBoard(position, mark).clear(mark)
    playTurn()
    winnerIdentified = false
}
else{
    console.log("Goodbye, see you again! ~(*.*)~");
    break; //close window once user decided to exit game
}}
```

Comment: Where is your `markBoard()` function?

Comment: function markBoard(position, mark) {
    board[position] =mark;
}